# How to form a government in the underworld?

Tags: government, low-fantasy, demons

During a business trip to hell one day, I managed to meet up with Mr. Satan and his adviser(pet) Mr. Hitler for an exclusive interview. Let's cut straight to the point I've found out that the lesser minions do not requires protection nor any other basic necessities such as food, water, shelter you name it and the reason is survival of the fittest which explain why the only dominating alpha male here is Mr. Satan himself. (Please ignore his pet in your answer!)

How do I convince the demons to hold a general election in hell?

Comment: So I see the "general election" question in here but it doesn't follow from the first paragraph.  Why would an exclusive interview lead to a general election in an environment that favors leadership by the strongest/most ruthless?

Comment: I'll agree that the context is absolutely baffling, but at the core I think there is an answerable question in here.

Comment: (a) There may be an answerable question, but first we need to understand user6760's premises. As indigochild's answer quite rightly points out, the phrase "survival of the fittest" implies that you can be killed... which certainly doesn't fit any description of Hell I've ever read!

Comment: (b) The traditional scenario for Hell is based on the Patriarchal concept that Heaven is ruled by Jehovah (or Yahweh), and Hell is ruled by Satan, who are omnipotent (all-powerful) within their realms. No opposition is possible in Hell -- Satan has all the power, so everything happens as he decrees. A different form of government could only happen if Satan chose to give up power -- and why would he? If user6760 is using different assumptions, different premises, then he needs to detail what they are so we can properly address his question.

Comment: I don't want to seem sacreligious, but did you visit Woodrow Wilson's office? I hear he [answers letters](http://www.video.theblaze.com/video/topic/43128422/v31182657/woodrow-wilson-gives-his-best-advicefrom-hell) from down there.

Comment: @Lensman: OTOH, if we accept the mythology, Lucifer only wound up running Hell because he led an unsuccessful revolution against Yahweh.  Which at least implies the possibility that his overthrow attempt could have succeeded, which in turn implies that he could possibly be overthrown.  Or maybe he's just tired of running the place - it can't be a whole lot of fun, doing it 24/7 for something over 6000 years now.

Comment: @jamesqf: (a) Well, we're both talking about the fact that different interpretations and therefore different scenarios are possible. I was thinking about Dante's INFERNO, where Satan has power in Hell only because Jehovah granted him that power; and it's no more possible to overcome that power than it is to directly overcome Jehovah's power. Note also that Dante has lesser powerful beings -- lieutenants  in Hell -- serving Satan directly. Any revolution would need to co-opt those lieutenants.

Comment: (b) But doing a bit of Wikipedia reading; Milton's PARADISE LOST suggests a literal military style war in Heaven, rather than just an analog of a child rebelling against a Patriarch. In the latter case, the child has no chance of winning, and is showing foolishness to think he does.The former case, with Satan leading a literal army, would suggest Satan was the first among equals (among angels), rather than actually having enough power of his own to contest with Jehovah directly; and that does raise the possibility that he's not omniscient even within Hell.

Comment: @Lensman: You do realize that it being impossible to overcome Jehovah's power is very useful propaganda, for Jehovah.  See for instance Kim Jong Un.

Comment: Check out the *Sandman Slim* series of novels.

Answer (score 2):

Since the context is a bit strange, I'm going to suggest that Hell is laid out in 9 circles as described in *The Inferno*, and elections serve simply to vote *deserving* people up or down the circles of hell.

Your initial assignments in the circles are from God Himself, so there is no provision in the ballot to vote yourself or your friends out of Hell. Your "positive" options are to get voted "upstream", since the higher circles are considered to be relatively nicer and more desirable than the lower circles. Alternatively, you will also be trying to knock people out of the higher circles and vote them into the lower circles.

Since this is Hell, after all, Satan isn't just going to hold elections every few years to move the circles around. Instead, he has taken back his most diabolical invention unleashed into the mundane world: FaceBook.

You are now locked in a permanent battle on FaceBook in Hell, trying to get enough "likes" to move up a circle or two while avoiding enough unlikes to be dropped into the lower circles. Diabolical links to Twitter, Snapchat and Instagram complicate your task (Deamons love posting pictures to Snapchat, for example), so you never know where the next threat is coming from among the billions of souls trapped in the Inferno.

God, in His mercy, has provided some relief. If you want, you can sign up for a MySpace account instead.....

Comment: The idea of voting to move people between circles is interesting. Why would anyone vote to move someone else up?

Comment: @indigochild - maybe it is the prisoner's dilemma? After all, I am pretty sure that Game Theory is diabolical. ....

(Thucydides this is brilliant)

Comment: @ Yvonne Yes. Since the premise of an election to change the "government" of hell makes no sense, using the FaceBook as a means of ramping the prisoner's dilemma to 11 seemed the closest way to meet the intent of the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely don't grasp the context you are providing at all. But the core seems to be:

Given these constraints, why would a leader hold a general election:

1. Denizens of the realm do not require physical things for survival (food, water, shelter, etc.)
2. Power is currently concentrated in a single person at the top (Satan)

### Popular Demand

An election can help to divert pressure from leaders, by providing legitimacy (whether it is an entirely free or fair election or not).

Can the dead die? If not, there is nothing stopping them from having a revolution any time. Death is typically a government's most final threat - without it, repression will be more difficult. This is especially true in your scenario where power is strongly concentrated on a single person.

Even if the dead don't have physical needs, they still have wants. They might experience social needs (acceptance, comfort, friendship), physical wants (comfortable furniture, food for the purpose of pleasure), status symbols (rank over others), or many other things.

If the dead in your world came from democratic nations (if Hitler is there, many of them will have) they may expect elections out of habit. Not having one may be reason enough to revolt.

### Relations with Other Realms

Elections can improve relations with other leaders.

Satan might be the only game in town, but perhaps he isn't the only town.  Are there other planes (Heaven, Niflheim, etc.) with rulers he might have to deal with? If so, an election (even an unfair one) might be advantageous. As a real world example, consider the many dictatorships (or weak democracies) that have unfair elections all the time.

### Identifying Enemies

Elections can weed out dissent.

One of the difficulties that anyone in politics faces is the lack of information.  Politicians (or leaders, generically) often don't know who their enemies are, what issues motivate them, where they are located, etc.

Democracies solve part of this problem with an election. Each side puts their people on a ballot, so everyone knows who the players are. Each side articulates their issues, identifies supporters, and so on.

This happens even when elections are not free. In the Soviet Union (for example), elections were common. Many parties ran. And the Communist Party watched with interest everyone who sympathized with the other parties.